# TrailingSwipeAction: How to deactivate auto delete on swipe through?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction, uicontextualaction

I update my tablerowactions to the swift 4 equivalent to be able to set icons instead of text as the buttons that show when the user swipes left on a table-element. My problem is that the first defined action (in my case the delete action) automatically gets triggered if the users swipe through from right to left instead of just showing all available actions. I would like to deactivate this behaviour. 
My code looks currently like this:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
        // implemantion of delete-button here 
        // ...

        success(true)
    })


    deleteAction.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "deleteIcon")
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = .red
    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UISwipeActionsConfiguration` has a property that allows you to turn this behavior off, called `performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe`. ([Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswipeactionsconfiguration/2902361-performsfirstactionwithfullswipe))

So instead of:

```
return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
```

do something like this:

```
let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
configuration.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
return configuration
```